# Tracking Increasing or decreasing prices in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to write a query that returns the id, product, price, and change columns. The change column should follow this logic. If the item price has increased it should write positive and if it has decreased negative depending on the product and excluding the first initial product price. The last product price should be taken into consideration.

This is how the result should look like.

```
id  product price   change
1   apple   1   
2   apple   1.5 positive
3   apple   3   positive
4   melon   4   
5   melon   3   negative
6   apple   2   negative
```

I have tried to use Case When statement but failed.

```
select 

p.id,
p.product,
p.price,
CASE
    WHEN p.product = p.product AND p.price > p.price THEN 'Positive' 
    WHEN p.product = p.product AND p.price > p.price THEN 'Negative' 
    END AS 'Change'

from products p
```

Create and insert statements

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `product` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

INSERT INTO products (id, product, price)
VALUES (1, 'apple', 1);
INSERT INTO products (id, product, price)
VALUES (2, 'apple', 1.5);
INSERT INTO products (id, product, price)
VALUES (3, 'apple', 3);
INSERT INTO products (id, product, price)
VALUES (4, 'melon', 4);
INSERT INTO products (id, product, price)
VALUES (5, 'melon', 3);
INSERT INTO products (id, product, price)
VALUES (6, 'apple', 2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select p.*,
       (case when lag(price) over (partition by product order by id) < price
             then 'negative'
             when lag(price) over (partition by product order by id) > price
             then 'positive'
        end)
from products p;
```

In archaic versions of MySQL, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*
       (case when prev_price < price
             then 'negative'
             when prev_price > price
             then 'positive'
        end)
from (select p.*,
             (select p2.price
              from product p2
              where p2.product = p.product and p2.id < p.id
              order by p2.id desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_price
      from product p
     ) p;
```

Comment: I have tried it several times but it gives me a syntax error. "Error: near line 25: near "over": syntax error"

Comment: I am running MySQL version 5.66.33. I guess this comes with version 8? Is there a solution for versions below 8?

Comment: @SPI . . . This requires MySQL 8+.  Your version of MySQL is over four years old.  You might want to update it.